# Создать и заполнить одномерный строковый массив

Tags: c#, массивы

Нужно создать одномерный строковый массив, размер в 7 ячеек. Заполнить его словами в следующем порядке:“люблю”, “я”, “смотреть”, “сложный”, “небо”, “на”, “очень”. Собрать в новом массиве полноценную фразу. На занятии использовали цикл for. Пустой цикл есть: string [] stroki = new string [7]; А вот как его заполнить и потом в нужном порядке вывести в фразу не могу понять. Пыталась создать переменную, чтобы туда присвоить слова, а потом из них из цикла for заполнять массив, но пишет ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь. С решением разобрались.

```
        string[] stroki = new string[7];

        stroki[0] = "Я ";
        stroki[1] = "сложный";
        stroki[2] = ", ";
        stroki[3] = "люблю ";
        stroki[4] = "смотреть ";
        stroki[5] = "на ";
        stroki[6] = "небо ";
        


        for (int i = 0; i < stroki.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(stroki[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Чтобы отметить вопрос решенным, выберите наиболее полезный ответ и поставьте зеленую галочку слева от него

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, о каком выводе идет речь, но вот один из вариантов инициализации массива с заданными значениями

```
var words = new[] {"люблю", "я", "смотреть", "сложный", "небо", "на", "очень"};;
```

Далее вывод одномерного массива с помощью `string.Join`

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", words));
```

Answer (score 0):

Если придерживаться задания, то если я правильно понял, пример такой. Учитывая что нужно заполнить строку в цикле, не используя `Join`

```
    string[] stroki = new string[7]{"люблю", "я", "смотреть", "сложный", "небо", "на", "очень"};
    string fullPhrase = "";
    
    for(int i=0; i<stroki.Length;i++){
    fullPhrase += stroki[i] + " ";
    }

Console.WriteLine(fullPhrase);
```